# Do emails sent with addresses set in setCcAddresses count against the daily email limit?

Tags: email, governorlimits, send-email

Will emails sent with values in setCcAddresses for external users count against our daily email limit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, each address counts towards the daily limit, and will count multiple times if they are duplicated. This is in the documentation for the sendEmail function.

Comment: Thanks, I only see in the documentation that setting the setToAddresses values to external users count against the limit. Do you have a link to where it specifies that emails that CC external users also count towards the limit?

Comment: @evelyn Any external addresses count towards the limit. Do you think they'd let you send yourself an email and CC or BCC 25 external addresses and not charge you for it? The 1,000 per day rule is to prevent mass email spamming.